# Henceforth, Henceforward, are they normally used?

Tags: word-choice

I am translating a document to english and there is a part in which I have to compare some objects, first on their *"current* state and then in the state that is going to be the standard from now on.

I am looking for one-words that denote this so I put

"Current"

"Henceforward".

I also read that this could be "Henceforth" or "Henceafter" ("from now on" is not a one-word)

Are they commonly used? Which one would be preferable?

Comment: Henceforth and Hereafter sound suitable. Not heard of Henceforward though

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine anyone using "Henceforth" unless they're a Shakespearean hero or a lawyer. It might be fine for an academic translation.

Here are some similar phrases and how common I perceive them:

Henceforward - I can understand this word but I've never seen it used. That's how formal/old fashioned it is.

Hereafter - Uncommon, mostly in older or formal texts

Henceforth - Uncommon, older and formal

Subsequently - Common, but implies immediately after

From now on/From then on - Common

Going forwards - Common